# Probability of an exam, what do you do?

Tags: probability

Suppose you have an exam that consists of **10 questions**, each having two options to choose from. Every correctly answered question gives you **1 point**, every unanswered question gives you **0 points**, and every wrongly answered question gives you **-0.5 points**. If you want to maximise your score and you do not know how to answer two out of the ten question, what do you do? What if you only didn't know one? *What if each question had three options and you didn't know how to answer one out of the ten questions?*

Comment: If you are asking about maximize the expected score then each unknown question has an expected value of $0$ whether you leave it blank or not so it makes no difference (from that point of view).  If you wanted to maximize something else you should clarify.

Comment: @lulu Is the expected value not  0.25 if you guess randomly?

Comment: Yes; guessing has a higher EV compared to leaving it blank.  Take your approach in how you got the EV of 0.25 and extend it to any number of options.

Comment: @user I was answering the italicized question, in which there are three options.  I agree that the true false version has expectation $.25$

Answer (score 0):

We can just consider maximizing the score on the two question out of the ten. If I don't answer, I'll get 0 points. If I answer randomly you can say I'll get 1 point from one and -0.5 from the other; so I'll get 0.5 So I should try answering.

You can repeat the same argument if you just have a question to answer.

If there are three option, if I don't answer I'll get 0; if I answer I'll get $1*1/3+2/3*(-0.5)=0 $. So the options are quite the same.